# MemoryCache for Object

Tags: c#, caching

I have various function classes that preform long calculation. Currently every access to the result of the functions means recalculating the functions. That's why I want to incorporate MemoryCache in my solution. But the problem is that I need a ChangeMonitor Class that monitors the function class for changes. I have seen examples that monitor a file. My question is: do I need to write a custom ChangeMonitor or am I missing a simple solution?

An example just to be clear:

```
class MyFunction
{
    //I want to monitor changes to these parameters
    private int param1;
    private int param2;

    //This result should be cached
    public int GetResult()
    {
        return param1 * param2;
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: When you say that you want to "monitor the function class for changes?, do you mean that you want to execute the calculation intermittently to see if the result changes?

Comment: Regarding caching method results, you could have a hashmap with the parameters and result added to it every time a calculation is complete. Then you just query the map for the parameters in the beginning of the method and return the result if it's there, and calculate a result if it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers.

I realized that if I want to use the ChangeMonitor class I would have to extend it to monitor memory segments. The better solution in my case would be to alert the cache that a function result has changed. I have done this by adding a method 'Reset' to MyFunction class. Every time a parameter changes I just call the Reset function which will invalidate the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Factory class to have a single class for access and creation of the MyFunction objects.
The Factory can then manage and synchronize the internal dictionary containing the previous calculations.
The MyFunction class needs to implement then IEquals and provide a hash function. Inside myClass you need to add private nullable int result.

Comment: Your implementation will work but you do not use MemoryCache which is a .Net class that supports a lot of functionality which I have to write myself when following your advise. Just take a look at CacheItemPolicy [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.aspx)